# Is there a name for ceiling (x / y)?

Tags: terminology, ceiling-and-floor-functions

The integer portion of a quotient, i.e. `floor (x / y)`, is sometimes referred to as "quotient" (e.g. Haskell defines a [`quot`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:quot) function).

Is there a name for `ceiling (x / y)`?

For example, given *x* items and containers of size *y*, the number of containers needed to hold the items is `ceiling (x / y)`. Is there a name for this?

Answer (score 1):

The reason $\mathrm{floor}(x/y)$ can be considered as a "quotient" function (when $x,y>0$) is because it corresponds precisely to the quotient in Euclidean division, i.e. which integer $q$ do we multiply by $y$ such that $a=qy+r$ for some remainder $0\leq r < y$. Many programming languages offer such a function for *integer division* because computationally, it's cheaper than using floating-point arithmetic to divide and then round the result. For instance, in Python you would do:

```
>>> 5 // 2
2
```

$\mathrm{ceil}(x/y)$ is less used, and anyway it's equal to $\mathrm{floor}(x/y)+1$ when $x,y>0$ (edit: and $x/y$ is not an integer, as pointed out by Hans in the comments), which is probably why there's no need to give it a distinct name.

Comment: If $x/y$ happens to be an integer, the ceiling and floor are equal, so that $+1$ only works if $x/y$ is not an integer.

Comment: I was originally computing it as *q + signum(r)*, exactly so I could avoid the need for a special case where *x/y* is an integer (so *r* is 0). *ceil(x/y)* seemed like a more straightforward way of expressing this, though it sounds like it might be less performant in terms of computing.

Answer (score 0):

You can notice that $$ \left\lceil\frac xy\right\rceil = -\left\lfloor\frac{-x}{y}\right\rfloor $$
so there's no need to define another function when you have already defined quotient.